# How to constrain a generic sequence parameter to a tuple in Swift 3?

Tags: swift, generics, swift3

In Swift 2, I was able to write a function which operated on any sequence of, for example, `(String, Int)`. It looked something like this:

```
func test<T: SequenceType where T.Generator.Element == (String, Int)>(input: T) {
    for (k, v) in input {
        print(k, "=", String(v))
    }
}
```

Using a tuple as the constrained type was particularly useful so that it could accept dictionaries, such as `[String:Int]`, as their sequence type consisted of tuples.

In Swift 3, I believe a similar function would be:

```
func test<T: Sequence>(input: T) where T.Iterator.Element == (String, Int) {
    for (k, v) in input {
        print(k, "=", String(v))
    }
}
```

But attempting to pass in a `[String:Int]`, for example: `test(input: ["a": 1, "b": 2])`, causes the error:

> Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred

As far as I can tell, dictionaries in Swift 3 still use a (Key, Value) tuple as their iterator type, so I think this should work. In fact, if I don't use a single type as the constrained iterator type, such as `where T.Iterator.Element == String`, I can pass in something such as a `[String]` and it works correctly.

Is there something I'm missing, or might this be a regression in Swift 3?

Comment: See the doc for Tuple type: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Types.html#grammar_tuple-type 
> When an element of a tuple type has a name, that name is part of the type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An interesting example.

Let's check the definition of `Dictionary` about conforming to `Sequence`:

```
public func makeIterator() -> DictionaryIterator<Key, Value>
```

And then `DictionaryIterator`:

```
public mutating func next() -> (key: Key, value: Value)?
```

So, for `Dictionary`, `T.Iterator.Element` seems to be `(key: Key, value: Value)`, not `(Key, Value)`.

If you rewrite your function as:

```
func test<T: Sequence>(input: T) where T.Iterator.Element == (key: String, value: Int) {
    for (k, v) in input {
        print(k, "=", String(v))
    }
}
```

this works:

```
test(input: ["a": 1, "b": 2])
```

But this does not work:

```
test(input: [("a", 1),("b",2)]) //->Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred
```

I'm not sure this is an intended feature or some sort of regression, or simply a bug.

Comment: Actually, I think I remember reading that tuples are more strict about their labels now, so it could be a feature. I'll see if I can find it...

Comment: I can't seem to find it now, but this basically solves the problem for me anyway. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is known bug ([SR-992](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-922)) which in some cases prevents the compiler from matching tuples of the same type, but different labels.

One possible workaround that would allow you to both pass sequences of `(String, Int)` or `(key: String, value: Int)` tuples and a `[String : Int]` dictionary would be to overload `test(input:)` with a function that expects a sequence with a `(key: String, value: Int)` element as an input. You could then use a lazily evaluated `map` in order to 'erase' the tuple labels and then pass that sequence onto your original implementation of `test`.

```
// Overload to deal with [String : Int] inputs – workaround for a bug.
func test<T: Sequence>(input: T) where T.Iterator.Element == (key: String, value: Int) {
    // 'Erase' the tuple labels with a lazily evaluated map(_:)
    // and pass the sequence onto the original implementation of test(input:)
    test(input: AnySequence(input.lazy.map{($0.key, $0.value)}))
}

func test<T: Sequence>(input: T) where T.Iterator.Element == (String, Int) {
    for (k, v) in input {
        print(k, "=", v)
    }
}

let d = ["foo" : 5]
let a = [("key", 3)]

test(input: d) // prints: foo = 5
test(input: a) // prints: key = 3
```

Perhaps not the most ideal solution – but as far as I can see there's no other easy workaround to this problem. Would certainly be interested if anyone has any better ideas.

Comment: Thanks, so it is a bug. Not too inconvenient to workaround, but hopefully it'll be fixed soon!

Answer (score 0):

It isn't for swift 3. However, it might help.

### Swift 4

Parameterised extensions are not allowed yet. So, we need to use function.

```
extension Result {
    func zip<A, B, C>(with other: Result<C, Failure>) -> Result<(A, B, C), Failure> where Success == (A, B) {
        return flatMap { (a, b) in
            Result<(A, B, C), Failure>.init(catching: {
                let c = try other.get()
                return (a, b, c)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Where `Result` is

```
public enum Result<Success, Failure: Error> {
    /// A success, storing a `Success` value.
    case success(Success)

    /// A failure, storing a `Failure` value.
    case failure(Failure)
}
```