# Understanding syntax for an array of tuples in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, syntax, tuples

I'm trying to understand syntax for arrays of tuples in Swift:

If I create a tuple:

```
var gameScore: (points: Int, player: String)
```

I can assign values like this:

```
gameScore = (1700, "Lisa")
```

And create an array of this tuple:

```
var gameScores = [gameScore]
```

I can append to the array this way:

```
gameScores.append((1650, "Bart"))
```

And this way:

```
gameScore = (1600, "Maggie")
gameScores += [gameScore]
```

But not this way:

```
gameScores += [(1600, "Maggie")]
```

Playground error is:

> Playground execution failed: error: Tuples Playground.playground:38:1: error: cannot convert value of type '[(points: Int, player: String)]' to expected argument type 'inout _'
>   gameScores += [(1600, "Maggie")]

However, this way works:

```
gameScores += [(points: 1600, player: "Maggie")]
```

Yes – I have code above that will work, but I'm trying to figure out what I'm not understanding in the failing syntax. Elements don't need to be named for the `.append()` method, but they need to be named for `+= [()]`.

Comment: The type checker in Swift 3 currently behaves a bit weirdly with tuple labels, see for example [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39785389/why-does-for-index-a-b-in-dict-enumerated-produce-an-error), [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39529357/how-to-constrain-a-generic-sequence-parameter-to-a-tuple-in-swift-3) and [this bug report](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-922).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Swift type inference system is being stretched to the point of breaking here. Swift is having trouble inferring the type of `[(1600, "Maggie")]` in your example. If you give it a little more information, your example will compile:

```
gameScores += [(1600, "Maggie") as (points: Int, player: String)]

gameScores += [(1600, "Maggie")] as [(points: Int, player: String)]
```

and

```
gameScores = gameScores + [(1600, "Maggie")]
```

all compile.

It seems Swift is having trouble inferring the type when `+=` is involved.

Looking at the definition of `+=`:

```
func +=<C : Collection>(lhs: inout Array<C.Iterator.Element>, rhs: C)
```

shows that the types of the `lhs` and `rhs` are different.  Swift is having trouble reconciling the types of the `lhs` and the `rhs` from the information given.  It seems to be starting with the `rhs` and then concludes that the type of the lefthand side is `inout _` and it tries to reconcile that with the type of `gameScores` which is `[(points: Int, player: String)]`.  Should it be able to infer the types?  Perhaps, but in this case, since you have an easy workaround, I say give the compiler a break and give it the explicit type information and make its job easier:

```
gameScores += [(points: 1600, player: "Maggie")]
```